# How to create a custom connection to WSL in remote host list?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, visual-studio-code

I am using visual studio and WSL on a company virtual machine. The consequence is that the ubuntu partition is shared among all the users of the machine.

To make sure we don't destroy each other work, the IT services have mounted a specific dir in the partition for each one of us and created a batch script to start VS code:

```
cd "E:\wsl\users\%USERNAME%\code"
set WSLENV=SECRET
wsl code .
```

Problem is I cannot reach this folder when opening a new visual studio window.

Would it be possible to create a custom connection to WSL pointing to this very folder and register it in the remote hosts ?

I can see it in the remote explorer but I would like to have it in the remote menu contextual view when opening a new window:

[image]

Comment: You cannot reach “E:\wsl\users\%USERNAME%\code” in within WSL or Windows? It should be accessible, in fact, you should be able to navigate to the directory within a Windows Terminal prompt and start Visual Studio using the command “WSL code .” manually. All the command does is sets the working directory for VS Code to the current directory

Comment: yes but the question is: can I register it in the remote host list ? the one you get when clicking on the bottom left btn. so that I can start new windows directly from VS code without opening a terminal

Comment: I don’t understand your question. You have installed Visual Studio Code within WSL not Windows, the solution if your looking to avoid launching a Windows Terminal prompt to start Visual Studio Code is to install it on Windows not Visual Studio which would require permission from your local IT Administrator

Comment: If I have WSL I am on a windows machine. If I try to connect to it it's implicitly because VSCode is on the Windows. the downvoted answer is close to a working solution. I'm adding an image  but I'm afraid this question is describing my issue.

Comment: The downvoted answer was generated by ChatGPT. So you want the “rambap” to be accessible without connecting to WSL?

Comment: nope. I would like to see the "rambap" target appear in the list as the default target of WSL. i.e. from VS code interface when I open the host list and click on WSL it would start in "/mnt/e/**/rambap" instead of "/home/lcd_user"